# What determines game or app differences of availability between countries?

Tags: google-play-store

There is a particular game which is in beta release in on country, in my country it is possible to register on a waiting list and in South America it just says "not available in your country". Is there a general explanation why the availability is different between different countries? Is it for marketing and purchase power adjustments or some other reason?

Comment: The most obvious reason for developers not to release an app in a specific region are missing localization and of course legal problems (app content not allowed or missing license for a specific country).

Comment: Software is considered a controlled export, and through embargo may be restricted from release to certain countries. Search for "Trade Compliance" and similar for the regulations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two factors

1. Google for reasons not made public has a list of countries where  app and Google Content is available [Country availability for Google Play apps & digital content](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2843119?hl=en).
2. Developers may choose targeted release for their own reasons. Google guidance on this - [Distribute app releases to specific countries - Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024?hl=en). I am not a developer but I guess reasons could include localization, scalability of app, revenue expectations, [taxation issues](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138000?hl=en), political reasons (Indian ban on Chinese apps recently comes to mind), reviews (I am aware of a famous developer who doesn't release his apps in some countries because of unfair reviews).

Comment: Are you sure about this ?  I have seen no evidence of this at all.  I always buy parallel imported Samsung phones which countries from all over the world.  They all can access the apps that I am supposed to.  What matters is the country of your Google account and the Country you are in.  The only thing I have noticed on one phone was that I could not get rid of Muslim holidays from the calendar.

Comment: Yes. FairEmail is an Email app, not available in India and some middle eastern countries. But is available in Europe /USA etc. I also linked console help (point 2) where developers can choose their countries of release//You are lucky if you didn't have this problem so far. //Chinese apps 70+ aren't available in India example: Camscanner